# C++ varargs - Is how I am using them okay or are they bad? Is there a good alternative?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, variadic-functions

The ultimate goal of this is to have a function which can take a variable number of arguments of a certain type (the same type, not different types), that can be declared on the function call.

As I'm using Visual Studio 2010, I CANNOT do:

```
MyFunction({1,2,3});
```

In an earlier question which was answered, I found I could use `boost::assign::list_of()`, however I discovered later that this [seems to have a bug of some kind](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7364) if you try to pass it only one parameter.

So I did some more searching and found that I could use variadic functions to achieve what I was aiming for.

```
void TestFunction2<int>(int count, ...)
{}
```

However, I wanted to restrict it by type, so eventually found I could do this with templates:

```
template <class T>
void TestFunction(const T& count, ...);

template <>
void TestFunction<int>(const int& count, ...);
```

Unfortunately, varargs things like `va_list` do not apparently like references.  The examples I saw to restrict types like this used const references.  If I remove the const reference aspect of the count parameter, it works as I want, but I don't know if this is going to lead to horrible side-effects down the road, OR if this whole varargs thing is a bad idea to begin with.

So I guess my question is, is what I'm doing in the last example above good or bad?  If it's bad, what is a good alternative so I can call a function with one or more parameters in-line like, say, `int` parameters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739358/passing-inline-double-array-as-method-argument

Comment: I can't use initializer lists in the version of C++ Visual Studio 2010 uses.

Comment: Ah, then the only alternative is hackish solutions (e.g. a wrapper class or var_args).  I highly advise against such approaches... they will make your code more cryptic and harder to read/edit/maintain.  Just declare a temporary array or its `STL` equivalents.  I know, I know it's an extra line, but it's better form.

Comment: The function will be called quite a lot, an extra line for the array declaration each time it is called is going to be pretty inconvenient.

Comment: how about `MyFunc(3, new []{1,2,3});` (see my updated answer).... that should work with your compiler (I'd assume).

Comment: With the use of the new keyword, I'll have to be responsible for `delete`ing it afterwards, yes?

Comment: Yes, that is correct... The pointer will be lost when it goes out of scope, leading to a memory leak.  STL types automatically clean up which is an advantage of them.

Comment: You can also initialize a `std::vector` in one or two calls, depending on your IDE's compiler version... see below...  this approach has advantages (built in count, sortable for basic types, etc.)

Comment: It's implementation defined whether you can pass objects that are not trivially copyable and trivially destructible via varargs, so in portable code you are limited to passing only certain types.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is `std::initializer_list<T>`, unfortunately this require C++11 support.

An alternative, that is nearly as elegant and easy enough to upgrade from, [is to use an array](http://ideone.com/d9sZa0):

```
#include <iostream>
 
template <typename T, size_t N>
void func(T (&s)[N]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        std::cout << s[i] << '\n';
    }
}
 
int main() {
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3};
    func(array);
}
```

When you move on to a compiler that supports initializer lists, [this can be changed into](http://ideone.com/m8AeKT):

```
#include <iostream>
 
template <typename T>
void func(std::initializer_list<T> s) {
    for (T const& t: s) {
        std::cout << t << '\n';
    }
}
 
int main() {
    func({1, 2, 3});
}
```

So both the function and call sites update will be painless.

*Note: the call site could be made completely similar using a macro, I advise against such approach, the purported gain is not worth the obfuscation.*

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
One more solution... if your compiler's IDE *partially* supports `C++11`, you may be able to initialize a `std::vector` at call time, i.e.

```
template <typename T>
void TestFunction(std::vector<T> vect)
{
....
}

....

TestFunction(std::vector<int>{1,2,3});
```

Advantages to this approach are that STL automatically frees the allocated memory when the function goes out of scope.

If that doesn't work you can resort to a two liner...

```
template <typename T>
void TestFunction(std::vector<T> vect)
{
....
}

....
std::vector<int> tmp(1,2,3);
TestFunction(tmp);
```

The big downside is that here the memory sits on stack until you leave that scope (or explicitly resize the vector to zero length.

Both approaches share some advantages... the count is built in and you have access to other useful member functions or affiliate methods (like `std::sort`).

......................................

Why not use variable arguments?
See the answer here, for example...
[Is it a good idea to use varargs in a C API to set key value pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866260/is-the-use-of-varargs-in-a-c-api-a-good-idea)

On non-`C+11` compliant compilers (like your IDE), you can try...

```
template <typename T>
TestFunction(const unsigned int count, T * arr)

TestFunction<std::string>(10, new string[] {"One", "Two", "Three"});
```

(Sounds like you can't use this in your IDE, but...)
If you're confident you're only compiling on modern machines and are primarily using simple types, this is best/most standards compliant solution...

As of `C++11` you can use `std::initializer` which is in `std::vector`:

```
#include<vector>

template <typename T>
void TestFunction(const std::initializer_list<T>& v)
{ }

int main()
{
    TestFunction<double>({1.0, 2.0});
    return 0;
}
```

..........................

...however this requires your compiler to be `C+11` so it's not perfectly portable.  For anything other than simple types, it also becomes harder to read.

I realize you say `on the function` call, but you may want to rethink that from a readability and ease of coding approach.

I agree with part of your approach -- what you want is to use a `template` function (this handles the variable `type`).  Before you call you initialize your collection of same-type elements into a temporary standard C array or a `std::vector`/`std::list` (STL's array wrapper).

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/

It's more lines of code, but it's much more readable and standardized.

i.e.

Rather than...

```
MyFunction({1,2,3});
```

Use:

```
template <typename T>
void TestFunction(const int count, T * arr)
{
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    .... arr[i] ... ; //do stuff
    ...
  }
}

int main()
{
  int * myArr = {1,2,3};
  TestFuntion<int>(3, myArr);
}
```

...or...

```
#include <vector>
template <typename T>
void TestFunction(std::vector<T> vect)
{
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
  {
    .... vect[i] ... ; //do stuff
    ...
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> myVect;
  myVect.push_back(1);
  myVect.push_back(2);
  myVect.push_back(3);
  TestFuntion<int>(myVect);
}
```

`std::list` would also be a perfectly acceptable, and may perform better, depending on your use case.